# Vuejs & FilePond files is not working. How to transfer loaded file to an object?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to use FilePond to Load images. But the current image in loading isn't transfered to my object. ( so i can use that object to send it to database ith axios)

My object is simply like that :

```
data:function() {
        return {
image:'',
}}
```

Then, my FilePond component is like that:

```
  <FilePond
    name="test"
    ref="pond"
    :maxFiles="max || 1"
    labelIdle="Drop files here..."
    allowMultiple="false"
    acceptedFileTypes="image/jpeg, image/png"
    :files="image"
    v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"/>
```

Thank you for you help if someone use FilePond with vuejs.

Answer (score -1):

According to [enter link description here](https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond) data:image should be array object.

```
data: function() {
    return { 
        image: [''] 
    };
},
```

Comment: As the author of FilePond I can confirm that you should be passing an array and not a single string.

Comment: @Yosuke Sato Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60219552/how-can-i-add-required-validation-on-filepond-vue