# How can I add required validation on filepond vue?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vue-component, vuetify.js, image-uploading

I read on this docs : https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond

I try to add like this  :

```
<FilePond 
    allowMultiple="true"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf"
    maxFileSize="2MB"
    required="true"/>
```

multiple, validation file type, max file works

But, required does not works

How can I solve this problem guys?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `v-bind:required` prop works:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <file-pond v-bind:required="true"/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond/issues/138